# secure notebook options

Tags: encryption, windows, bios

How can I secure my notebook with highly sensitive information stored in a spreadsheet.

I am keeping the following options in mind:

- Password protect & encrypt BIOS
- Full disk encryption
- Password protect the spreadsheet

Is it possible to do 2fa for windows signon? 
What about remote tracking & wiping?

Which other options are there to explore?

Bearing in mind there is still an end-user that needs to use this notebook.

Comment: In addition to what you have listed, I would suggest buying a notebook with soldered RAM and hard drive to prevent against "insert into my machine and copy" attacks.

Comment: You can solder it yourself: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoxy  
Epoxy glue can be removed with heat and scrape.

Comment: As for your options, full disk encryption is #1 here. BIOS password can be removed with physical reset button on motherboard (or simple re-cabling), but if system is encrypted BIOS access won't be nearly as useful.

Comment: At the end of the day, Law #3 of Security: "If a bad guy has unrestricted physical access to your computer, it's not your computer anymore". These tricks will make it _harder_ to steal your spreadsheet, but the best practice is still to never let the laptop out of your sight, and other common-sense things, which trumps any amount of technology.

Comment: secure against whom?

Comment: Scary example of Mike's advice: http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/definition/evil-maid-attack

Comment: Even scarier if the computer is 'equipped' with Absolute Computrace:  https://securelist.com/analysis/publications/58278/absolute-computrace-revisited/

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer but I want to highlight an aspect you did not mention. Apart from physical security (temper prevention and detection?) and encryption you have to be very careful what you are doing.

That means that no process having direct internet connection (web surfing, chat, skype...) or which has indirect connection (mail) should be able to access any sensitive data. The best would probably to have no internet connection at all. Another option would be to only access the internet through a companies VPN where you hopefully get the needed protection.

Unfortunately you often need direct internet access to at least establish a WLAN connection (because of capture portals) which you can use with your VPN. So one option would be to have a virtual machine and only do any connection from inside this machine.

Answer (score 0):

> Password protect & encrypt BIOS

Protects against trivial access but not much more and not a targeted attack.

> Full disk encryption

If the 'key' of said encryption is not on the laptop (but on for example a external smart card) than this prevents stealing of the data by just having the machine and when used properly it also prevents  sniffing the key directly from memory. downside is that is slows your PC a lot.

> Password protect the spreadsheet

Protects against trivial access but not much more and not a targeted attack.
It is easy to brute force as its purpose is only to protect in the office environment not an security theater.

> Is it possible to do 2fa for windows signon? What about remote tracking & wiping?

Not without a third party (and hardware)

> Which other options are there to explore?

I would use something like a strong PGP encryption key, with a [yubikey](https://www.yubico.com/products/yubikey-hardware/yubikey-neo/) on which the secret key is stored. and the spreadsheet (does it really need to be a spreadsheet, wouldn't a csv be sufficient?) is stored encrypted, and needs the 'key' to be decrypted. The other useful things would be to implement Disk encryption and a Boot (BIOS) password. these are to make it harder to mess with the machine.

If your using a *NIX system I would also deploy [CSF](http://configserver.com/cp/csf.html)Firewall and its LFD intrusion detection.

If this file is as risky as you make it seem, you should stay clear from any system you can not fully audit. so a Security hardened OS would be best.

It all depends on risk assessment and security needs.